# I can't add UserControl to Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls

I have problem. I can't add UserControl to my main Form. I can add only 1 UserControl named "nickname" but i can't add my second UserControl named "usermain". When i trying add "usermain" UserControl then i get this error:

```
Unable to create component 'usermain'. Error message: 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an object instance in IMP View.usermain.Usermain _Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C: \ Users \ Robert\ source \ repos \TMP View\ usermain.cs:line 29 in System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl0 in System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean flgnoreVisible) in System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl0 in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Contro I value) in System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner.AddCh ildControl(Control newChild) in System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner.AddCo ntrol(Control newChild, (Dictionary defaultValues) in System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.lnitializeNew Component(IDictionaty defaultValues) in System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(1 DesignerHost host, (Dictionary defaultValues) in System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponents(IDesi gnerHost ho...'
```

I don't know what i should do...

In "usermain" i have only this code:

```cs
public partial class usermain : UserControl
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        public usermain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Usermain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var json = wc.DownloadString("https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/" + Properties.Settings.Default.SteamID);
            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            var response = root.response;
            var error = root.error;
            profile_img.ImageLocation = response.avatar;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you try adding the Usermain_Load method in a try catch block and go through the handled Exception?

Comment: So, what is on line 29? Note that it is sometimes necessary/helpful to put some initialization code in an `if(!DesignMode){..}`block.

Comment: @Democrats when i add try catch i get this error "System.NullReferenceException: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in TMP_View.usermain.Usermain_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\...\usermain.cs:line 31"

Comment: @Taw now in line 31
In line 31 it's: profile_img.ImageLocation = response.avatar;
in response.avatar its url link to image from API JSON. So i can't do this?
URL looks like this: https:\/\/static.truckersmp.com\/avatarsN\/defaultavatar.png

Comment: What's probably happening is that you are referring to the profile_img object before it has been initialized

Comment: add a check for the profile_img != null before setting the responce avatar

Comment: @Democrats
Before this User must give a SteamID - if SteamID its correct then this ID was be saved in Properties.Settings (...) and after this usermain is showed and image in  Picturebox it's avatar from example "api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/76561198258946551".

Comment: Set a breakpoint to that line and test what is null, most likely `response`, possilby `response.avatar`. Then think about why that is so.. Always use the debugger before coming here!

Answer (score -1):

Surround your Load event with a

```c
if(!DesignMode)
{
...
}
```

Or

```c
if(DesignMode) return;

…
```